# SQL query using index on timestamp with timezone column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, querying

PostgreSQl
I have table like this:

```
create table if not exists some_table
               (
        some_id         varchar(40)              not null,      
        
        created_at      timestamp with time zone not null,
        
        constraint some_pkey
            primary key (some_id)
```

next step i created index on created_at field

```
create index concurrently if not exists some_table__created_at
        on statement (created_at);
```

i can't create partial index on created_at with condition because this condition includes mutable values

if i use query like this:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
select t1.created_at
FROM some_table t1
where t1.created_at < '2023-06-19 10:17:20.830627+00:00';
```

index scan is working

```
Index Only Scan using statement__created_at on statement t1  (cost=0.42..5991.71 rows=210245 width=8) (actual time=0.016..27.510 rows=210277 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (created_at < '2023-06-19 10:17:20.830627+00'::timestamp with time zone)
  Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.098 ms
Execution Time: 37.884 ms
```

But i want to get field some_id with using index scan

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
select t1.some_id
FROM statement t1
where t1.created_at < '2023-06-19 10:17:20.830627+00:00';
```

and here i get

```
Seq Scan on statement t1  (cost=0.00..6535.50 rows=210245 width=37) (actual time=0.007..33.904 rows=210277 loops=1)
  Filter: (created_at < '2023-06-19 10:17:20.830627+00'::timestamp with time zone)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 2723
Planning Time: 0.099 ms
Execution Time: 44.463 ms
```

I tried to use index on 2 columns(some_id and created). It didn't help me.

Maybe i should use not btree index or something else?

Comment: is "FROM statement t1" in your 2nd query a typo? You don't need to create an index for columns in the select clause, only those in the where clause.

Comment: 1) You need to clean up your question. a) `create table if not exists some_table` vs `create index concurrently if not exists some_table__created_at on statement (created_at);` Doesn't match.  b) `select t1.created_at FROM some_table t1 ...` vs  `select t1.some_id FROM statement t1 ...` doesn't match. 2) As @gbjbaanb said the index is for what is in the `WHERE` and in both cases that is `created_at`. FYI, `constraint some_pkey  primary key (some_id)` will create an index on `some_id`.

Comment: Why would you want to use an index anyway if you want to return almost 99% of the table?

Comment: it was typo, about statement table. I tried to make simple example. I didn't renamed all variables =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there no *index-only-scan* when you select the `some_id` field? Because an [index-only-scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) is performed when all the data required can be fetched from the index and so the actual table has not to be visited at all. When you select the `some_id` field the actual table has to be visited anyways to fetch the values for that field.

In that scenario it depends on the [selectivity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/row-estimation-examples.html) of your where clause. If the planner determines that your where clause has a bad selectivity, i.e. it will select most of the rows, then it makes sense to do a sequential table scan even if an index is available because there is no point in visiting the index first if afterwards almost all of the table has to be loaded anyways to get the data from the matching rows.

To verify this behaviour make sure you have decent amount of rows in the table (a million maybe?) and use a timestamp in your where clause that matches only a small portion of those. You should see a query plan that uses the index instead of doing a sequential scan, although it will not be an index-only-scan.

Comment: oh thx for the asnwer. I changed condition ">" and analyse  showed me bitmap scan

Comment: @Griffith I'm glad I could help. If the answer solved your problem you can set it to *accepted* so other people know they can open this question and find a valid answer.